# Using wget to download multiple urls.

Tags: wget

I have a file urls.txt. Which has multiple urls.
I am using wget to download the web content like this:
wget -i urls.txt. The web content is getting saved in different different files for each link. I want it to save everything  in a single txt file

Answer (score 0):

This will store the request details to messages.txt and all of the downloaded content to html.txt

```
$ wget -a messages.txt -i urls.txt -O html.txt
```

From `wget --help`:

```
Logging and input file:
  -a,  --append-output=FILE        append messages to FILE

Download:
  -O,  --output-document=FILE      write documents to FILE
```

Tested on GNU Wget 1.19.1 built on darwin16.6.0.